# differentiable $f: R\to R$ satify $f(f(x))=f(x)$, show $f$ is constant, or $f(x)=x$

Tags: calculus

[$f(f(x))=f(x),$ for all $x\in\Bbb R$ suppose $f$ is differentiable, show $f$ is constant or $f(x)=x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4206147/ffx-fx-for-all-x-in-bbb-r-suppose-f-is-differentiable-show-f-is)

But I could not pass, since $[f'(f(x))-1](f(x))=0$ do not imply $f'(f(x))=1$ or $f'(x)=1$.